# Online French newspapers, magazines, etc, with English translation

Tags: traduction, ressources, apprentissage

I'm learning French.  I'm mostly interested in sciences (social sciences in particular) and humanities.  Someone suggested I read newspapers.  Though not a big fan of politics, with Trump coming to power I thought maybe I have to now. :)

Anyhow, I've looked at *Le Monde* and put a few articles into google translate but that doesn't work well for me.

There is also *Le Monde Diplomatique*, which is published in several languages.  However, the different versions don't contain the exact same articles!

In short, what I need is a French newspaper, magazine, or blog, where the same content is written in both French and English, and of course the translation being of the same high caliber.

Thanks for your help.

---

J'apprends le français.  Les humanités et les sciences (sociales) m'intéresse le plus.  Quelqu'un m'a proposé de lire les journaux.  Je ne suis pas un adepte des politiques mais après l'arrivé au pouvoir de Trump, je crois qu'il faut qu'on suive l'actualité maintenant. :)

Dans tous les cas, j'ai jeté un œil au journal **Le Monde**, et mis quelques articles dans le Google Translate, mais pour moi ça ne marche pas bien.

Il y'a aussi **Le Monde Diplomatique**, qui est publié en plusieurs langues.  Mais les différentes versions ne contiennent pas exactement les mêmes articles !

Bref, j'ai besoin de journaux, de magazines et de blogs français, où le même contenu est rédigé en français et en anglais, et la traduction étant d'une même qualité élevée.

Merci de votre aide.

Answer (score 5):

## Simple French

Unfortunately I can't comment yet, because I'm not sure if something like [French English News](http://www.frenglishnews.com/) is quite what you're looking for or if it is a little too simple. Therefore I'll leave that coupled with another recommendation.

## Slightly More Advanced French

A site like *[Slate France](http://www.slate.fr/)* is not too bad. I assume you're familiar with the original English version of *Slate*. You'll have to put in a little bit of effort though. For example, you can perform a search for "[traduit par](https://www.google.be/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-iswWI3sO4bH8AferY34Bg#q=site:slate.fr+%22traduit+par%22)."

- A result I picked out at random is "[Le dad bod expliqué par la science](http://www.slate.fr/story/104802/peres-kilos-grossesse)" written by Hanna Rosin.
- A subsequent search for some relevant keywords like "Hanna Rosin" and "dad bod" on "site:slate.com" yields the original article: "[Dads Can Also Flaunt Their Post-Baby Bods, According to Science](http://www.slate.com/blogs/xx_factor/2015/07/21/fatherhood_makes_men_fat_new_study_explains_the_dad_bod.html)."

The same trick also works on the *Le Monde Diplomatique* website which you mentioned yourself, except there the relevant keywords are "translated by." I note that these two articles are the same, for example, by searching for the name of the author (Florence Beaugé), and a relevant term from the article that's unlikely to be translated (Tiffany Runion).

- "Unequal state of the union." http://mondediplo.com/2016/11/12uswomen
- "Toutes les Américaines ne s’appellent pas Hillary Clinton." https://www.monde-diplomatique.fr/2016/11/BEAUGE/56756

It's too bad that they don't make it any easier on you by linking to the original from which it is translated or even mentioning the original title.

Comment: J'allais répondre avec Slate. Je pense qu'on peut aussi citer Huffington Post.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to have a look at the website of "Courrier international": it offers a selection of articles from various newspapers and magazines around the world, all translated in French (and the quality of the translations is quite high, often with some notes on cultural items, etc). You can look up by source, and select English-speaking sources from here : http://www.courrierinternational.com/notule-source. The online articles also have a link to the original one if it is available. Take for instance this article: http://www.courrierinternational.com/article/2014/04/21/le-capitalisme-se-mord-la-queue. You will find a link named "lire l'article original" at the end. But remember, "Courrier international" is targeted at French native speakers, so I imagine it may sometimes be as difficult as reading "Le Monde". However, I am sure you will find articles that will fit your interests, it is very varied. Bon courage !